# Right Installation of Open AM J2EE Policy Agent

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, single-sign-on, openam

i want to install the Open AM J2EE Policy Agent.
I created a J2EE Agent in Open Am successfully.

For the installation i use following parameters :

ServerURl to OpenAM :  http://127.0.0.1:8080/openam

Path to Tomcat Config : %PATH TO TOMCAT CONFIG

J2EE Agent URL : http://127.0.0.1:8080/agentapp as set in the open am app

Agent-Name : J2EEAgent

Path to Password : /tmp/pwd.txt

The installation runs successfully. But I'm not able to start tomcat after the installation. The console shows some errors but disappears too quickly.

Has everyone a simple user guide to install the policy agent in tomcat 7 and open am 14 (nightly build). Or did you see any failure on my side.

Greetings

Comment: amAuthContext:05/17/2016 11:23:45:321 AM MESZ: Thread[main,5,main]: TransactionId[unknown]
ERROR: Failed to obtain auth service url from server: null://null:null
amNaming:05/17/2016 11:23:46:368 AM MESZ: Thread[main,5,main]: TransactionId[unknown]
ERROR: Naming service connection failed for http://127.0.0.1:8080/openam/namingservice
com.iplanet.services.comm.client.SendRequestException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: And tomcat ejects the error:

'debugconfig.properties' isn't valid, the default configuration will be used instead: Can't find /.debugconfig.properties

Comment: amAuthContext:05/17/2016 11:23:45:321 AM MESZ: Thread[main,5,main]: TransactionId[unknown] ERROR: Failed to obtain auth service url from server: null://null:null amNaming:05/17/2016 11:23:46:368 AM MESZ:

Comment: And jet ? What should i do ?

Comment: amAuthContext:05/17/2016 11:23:45:321 AM MESZ: Thread[main,5,main]: TransactionId[unknown] ERROR: Failed to obtain auth service url from server: null://null:null amNaming:05/17/2016 11:23:46:368 AM MESZ:

is not an error - https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-1106

However you specified 

ServerURl to OpenAM : http://127.0.0.1:8080/openam

hence the agent tries to reach OpenAM using this URL ... this can not work. 

Also note that J2EE Policy Agent and OpenAM can not run in the same deployment container

Comment: Also if you do not use host-based cookie (which is not the default) you can not use 'localhost' for OpenAM as the browser must reject a domain cookie issued  for localhost, a public suffix or an IP